# where I have to check variables value or global variable

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a code

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{!$Setup.websiteSystemVariables__c.Main_URL__c+$CurrentPage.Name}"/>
```

I want to check from where

`$Setup.websiteSystemVariables__c`     and

`$CurrentPage.Name`

values are coming..
I page view source this is visible as a  --

```
<link href="xyz.comhomepageAB" rel="canonical" />
```

But I want it to be --

I want to add back-slash between URL and page name as i mentioned in URL--

```
 <link href="xyz.com/homepageAB" rel="canonical" />
```

I am not able to fix this bug..

I researched on this .. I checked on classes, component but I m not able to solve this..
Please help me out ..

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full explanation of things you asked for**

`$Setup.websiteSystemVariables__c` will be a name of custom setting object `(Setup->Develop->Custom Settings)`. You probably have the setting already (otherwise page wouldn't compile). Check if there's at least 1 row there and has something meaningful in the `Main_URL__c` field. Remember that if you're in developer sandbox (not a full copy one) data is not copied from production so most likely your setting is empty. Looks like it's a hierarchy setting - add the data on "organization" level and you're good to go.

`$CurrentPage.Name` is whatever is the name of your Visualforce page (`homepageAB`?) You can read a bit more about it [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_variables_global.htm?SearchType=Stem) and if you need - experiment with merge fields that'd mimic the methods from [PageReference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm?SearchType=Stem) class (minus the "get..." part).

**Solution to your actual problem ;)**

Either go to this custom setting and modify the value in "Main URL" to add the backslash (so "`xyz.com/`") or modify the code to this:

```
href="{!$Setup.websiteSystemVariables__c.Main_URL__c+ '/' + $CurrentPage.Name}"
```

Just check what value you have on production and use same format in your sandbox, otherwise you might end up with 2 backslashes in the URL...

Comment: You're welcome :) Although I have no idea why you decided to break the links to the Salesforce VF developer guide ;) Now it looks weird with "[PageReference][2]" in the text and the link listed on the bottom.